# Automapper If source is null, set destination object properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have the following case:

**Source**:

```
public class AccountLogin
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public bool AccountVerified { get; set; }
}
```

This object is returned from the database, so if no user is found it **could be null**

**Destination**:

```
public class LoginUserResponseModel
{
    public bool AccountExists { get; set; }
    public bool AccountVerified { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need?
If the source is null, I need an instance of the destination object with the following parameters:

```
{
    "AccountExists": false,
    "AccountVerified": false
    "Status": "Error"
    "Token": null
}
```

The `AutoMapper` code I put into my `MappingProfile.cs` file is as follows:

```
 CreateMap<AccountLogin, LoginUserResponseModel>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.AccountExists, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src == null ? false : true))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src == null ? "Error" : "Ok"));
```

This code works fine when the object is not null, it sets `Status = "Ok"` and `AccountExists = false`

When I have received existing user from the database, my source, `AccountLogin`, e.g:
[image]

So this maps correctly like this:
[image]

The problem is when the source is null, the destination is also null:

[image]

I have a lot of workarounds, but I am really curious if this could be made with `AutoMapper`.
The project I am using is `ASP Net Core 2.2` and `AutoMapper v6.1.1`

Comment: Can you do the code images as code?

Comment: TBH, I don't recommend using AutoMapper for anything other than 1:1 mappings (I think even Jimmy Bogard says this). Might be worth considering just writing your own mappers for these more complex cases - the resulting code will likely be simpler and more compact that the comparable AutoMapper config!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, may do exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comments I would suggest using a CustomTypeConverter: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html

```
public class AccountLoginConverter : ITypeConverter<AccountLogin, LoginUserResponseModel>
{
    public LoginUserResponseModel Convert(AccountLogin source, LoginUserResponseModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if(source == null)
        {
            return new LoginUserResponseModel { AccountExists = false, Status = "Error" }
        }

        // You can have more complex logic here      

        return new LoginUserResponseModel
        {
            AccountExists = true,
            AccountVerified = true, // Or more logic
            Status = "Ok"
        };
    }
}
```

In order to set up with your newly designed converter:

```
cfg.CreateMap<AccountLogin, LoginUserResponseModel>().ConvertUsing(new AccountLoginConverter());
```

or

```
 cfg.CreateMap<AccountLogin, LoginUserResponseModel>().ConvertUsing<AccountLoginConverter>();
```

Comment: This doesn't do the trick for me, can you further help and I will accept the answer. So first this does not compile, `new AccountLogin` should be `new LoginResponseModel`. Also when fixing this, it still returns `null`, if the source is `null`.

Comment: Also when the source is existing (we have an instance of `AccountLogin`) the property `AccountVerified` is not mapped. An solution is to add it as follows `new LoginUserResponseModel { AccountExists = true, Status = "OK", AccountVerified = true }`. But there could be a case where is not verified. And if I add more properties in the future I want them to be mapped normally. So my initial problem - if the source is `null` map only two properties in the destination. If not `null` mapp as we normally would.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I'll give an upvote. Will accept if a solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

You could try ConvertUsing with a custom ITypeConverter:

```
public class MyConverter : ITypeConverter<AccountLogin, LoginUserResponseModel >
{
    public int Convert(AccountLogin source, LoginUserResponseModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new LoginUserResponseModel{
           AccountExists = source == null ? false : true,
           AccountVerified = false,
           Status = source == null ? "Error" : "Ok",
           "Token": null
        };
    }
}
```

Then map it with:

```
CreateMap<AccountLogin, LoginUserResponseModel>().ConvertUsing(new MyConverter());
```

Comment: I believe this could do the trick. Few notes: If I receive `AccountLogin` from the database it could have either `AccountVerified` `true` or `false`. So this line `AccountVerified = false`, should be like that: `AccountVerified = source.AccountVerified`. Another thing I don't really like is, that I lose flexibility like that. If I add more properties in the `AccountLogin` and the same properties in `LoginUserResponseModel` in order for them to be mapped, I have to come and add them in `MyConverter` as well. Although they have the same name. Thanks for the answer, 1 upvote.

Comment: Probably I will end up doing it like that: I will make sure I will not pass `null` to `this.mapper.Map<LoginUserResponseModel>(user)`